# Remove All Lines Without @ Sign

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I'm trying to basically do the opposite of http://www.udel.edu/topics/software/general/editors/unix/vi/delsearch.html which suggests this:

```
grep -v @ oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

But instead of outputting files that DO NOT have the @ sign in them, I just want to output the files that DO have the @ sign in them to a new file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-v` option to `grep` means "inverted match". Simply remove it and that's how `grep` is used normally:

```
grep '@' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

In general, simple use case of grep:

```
grep "search_pattern_here" input_filename_here > output_filename_here
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *that* simple as :

```
grep '@' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

**NOTE**

- `-v` means `invert mode`

Comment: To add: the -v option of grep "inverts" the selection (returns only lines that do not match the pattern). Just so that OP sees what's going on here